# Has every Lusin vector space a stronger Polish vector space topology?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a topological vector space or even a locally convex space such that its (vector space) topology is Lusin, i.e. there is some stronger Polish topology. Does there also exist a stronger Polish topology under which $X$ is a topological vector space or even locally convex?

Similarly, if $X$ is a Souslin vector space topology then it is [known](https://books.google.de/books?id=0efjBwAAQBAJ) (p. 4) that there exists a stronger Souslin metrizable topology. Does there also exist a stronger Souslin metrizable vector space topology?

Comment: A possible obstacle is the open mapping theorem: An ultrabornological l.c.s. does not have a strictly finer Frechet space topology. One would thus need some finer complete metrizable separable topology e.g. on $s'$, the space of sequences of at most polynomial growth.